# How to use this rack middleware with a Rails 3.x app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

Found this gem [Rack After Reply](https://github.com/oggy/rack_after_reply) that says:

A hook for Rack apps which fires after the response has been sent, and the socket to the client has been closed.
This is the ideal time to perform delayable, non-backgroundable tasks, such as garbage collection, stats gathering, flushing logs, etc. without affecting response times at all.

#### Usage

Simply add your callbacks to `env['rack_after_reply.callbacks']`.

```
use Rack::ContentLength
use Rack::ContentType, 'text/plain'
run lambda { |env|
  env['rack_after_reply.callbacks'] << lambda { ... }
  [200, {}, ['hi']]
}
```

But I couldn't fit it into the Rails3 app.

Can anyone say on how to use this with a Rails3 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the callbacks to the Rack env during the actual request, i.e. in your controller.

You can get at the Rack env with the `request` object.

In your controller:

```
def index #or whatever your method is, you could do this in filter
  #normal controller code...

  request.env['rack_after_reply.callbacks'] << lambda do
    $stderr.puts "Hello from callback"
  end
end
```

The callback will be run after any request that gets routed to this method.

Comment: thanks. Looks like this is the solution. I'll try this out and come back.

Answer (score 0):

simply adds this line `config.middleware.use(new_middleware, args)` in your application.rb or in  the specific environment.rb file.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack

Comment: Before asking here, I've went through many posts on using middleware with Rails3 stack.
But almost everyone was pointing to using the middleware the rails guides page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack

If you look at the above question carefully, I am having the problem with this `env['rack_after_reply.callbacks'] << lambda { ... }`. 

How to pass that callback?  Here is the backtrace of my stupid try. https://gist.github.com/2592418